# What's the best a way to upload multiple PDF files at once and rename it on the go?

Tags: interaction-design, uploading

I am working on contactless menu generator, where the user can upload pdf files (breakfast, lunch etc)so that the customer can see them when the QR code is scanned.

issue: What is the best way to upload multiple files at a time and also rename them, plus add the timings?

Comment: I don't really see a need for the user to upload multiple documents at a time. I mean, we are talking like ~3 uploads per user. It's not exactly a time sink to upload them one by one. Especially if you expect the user to modify each one (i.e. the name). Just have the user select a file, choose a name, then click an "upload" button. Nice and simple. They can repeat that 2-3 times without difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, let users upload 1 PDF file at a time. Then you can put a text box next to the file input and let users do it there and then.

If you expect this functionality to be used a lot on a repeated basis it may be helpful to upload multiple PDF files in one go (as shown below):

[image]

If you go for the latter, then you can play back all of the successfully uploaded files with a text box to rename the file.